Use Custom fields for aspnetidentity
I am using asp.netcore7 and I have telerik blazor project that I use AspnetcoreIdentity for register or login users in my app.How can i use custom fields like firstname,lastname,address,postalcode,... for aspnetcore.identity?

Just create a custom User Entity inherit from IdentityUser
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // Add custom properties here
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

Then make sure the ApplicationDbContext inherit from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }

Finallly, replace all the IdentityUser with ApplicationUser throughout the project. Extend your registeration logic to accept additional fields.
